# Testing convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Lets have a series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

However, I have absolutely no clue how to try to continue. I could probably use the integral criterion and integrate the problem using the residue theorem, but that is too much of a hassle. Is there an easy way to prove the convergence of this series?

Comment: Try ratio test.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Sorry but no, I will not.

Comment: @Did It's ok. I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, (limit or not) comparison:

$$\frac{n+1}{n-1}=1+\frac2{n-1}\implies\log\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)\le\frac2{n-1}\implies$$

$$\frac{\log\frac{n+1}{n-1}}{\sqrt n}\le\frac2{(n-1)\sqrt n}$$

and the series converges by (limit, say) comparison with $\;\sum\frac1{(n-1)\sqrt n}\;$

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know, that the inequality $\ln(1+x)\leq x$ holds, only that $\ln(1+x)<(1+x)$ and therefore I was confused a lot... Maybe I should study taylor polynomials more...

Comment: @user74200 **Much** more than what you need, but a good table for inequalities: http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf

(The inequality $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ can be proven by convexity of the function $f\colon x\in(-1,\infty) \mapsto \ln(1+x)$, since $f(x) \leq f(0)+f'(0)x = x$.)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)\sim\frac2{n-1}\sim\frac2n$$
so the given series is convergent by asymptotic comparaison with the series $\sum\frac1{n\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), and the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test):

The general term of your series is, when $n\to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{\frac{2}{n}+ o(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
$$
so by the limit comparison test you series converges (at the same rate as the series $\sum_n \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}$.)

---

We used the facts (low-order Taylor expansions) that, when $u\to 0$,
$$
\ln(1+u) = u+o(u), \qquad\text{and} \qquad \frac{1}{\frac{1}{u}-1} = u + o\left(u\right)
$$

Comment: A message I am repeating quite often: while it's not always the most elegant, Taylor expansions are a systematic, versatile, and powerful tool, applicable in a variety of contexts (this one, limits, asymptotics of functions, of sequences, etc.) Learning how to use them is most likely a good idea.