# Testing convergence of a series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{\cosh(\pi/n)}{\cos(\pi/n)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Given series
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{\cosh(\pi/n)}{\cos(\pi/n)}\right)$$
I should test convergence. I know, that I should use a comparison criterion. I tried expressing $$2\cosh(x)=e^x+e^{-x}$$
but got nowhere. What is the correct approach?

Comment: Let $\frac{\cosh x}{\cos x}=1+\epsilon(x)$, can you identify the behaviour of $\epsilon(x)$ when $x\to0$?

Comment: Recurring theme: you can use Taylor expansions, here of $\cos,\cosh$ and $x\mapsto\ln(1+x)$ when $x\to 0$. It's systematic, and it works.

Comment: Both $\log\cos(z)$ and $\log\cosh(z)$ behave like $O(z^2)$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, hence the series is trivially convergent by comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurring theme: you can use Taylor expansions, here of $\cos, \cosh$ and $x\mapsto\ln(1+x)$ when $x\to 0$. It's systematic, and it works.

**In detail:**
$$\begin{align}
\cosh \frac{\pi}{n} &= 1+\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
\cos \frac{\pi}{n} &= 1-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align}
\ln \frac{\cosh \frac{\pi}{n}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{n}}
&= \ln \frac{1+\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{1-\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}
= \ln \left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) 
\right)\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\ln \left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
so by comparison with the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ your series is convergent.

---

*We used, on top of the Taylor expansions of $\cos$ and $\cosh$ to second order, the low-order expansions of $\ln(1+u)$ and $\frac{1}{1+u}$ around $0$, all of them quite standard.*

Comment: Based on this one and [your last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814474/testing-convergence-of-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac-ln-left-fracn1n-1-r), both being about series whose convergence can be "attacked" by the above approach: studying Taylor-based arguments may be a good idea.

Comment: (Backed up by [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812627/modern-calculus-or-analysis-text-that-emphasizes-landau-notation), I'd -- again -- argue that this is often the easiest way to tackle many problems. Not necessarily the most elegant, but definitely one of the most, if not the most, systematic.)